# Changing the site url

Tags: facebook, authorization, token

We have an app with some users. The users have already granted authorization for my app an specific domain.

If I change the Site Url (App Settings), my users will have to grant authorization again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your APP ID and Secret remain the same, so no re-authorization will be required.

Answer (score 1):

no, identification is made ​​by the token and not the url